# C# Newtonsoft.Json Convert type

Tags: c#, json, types

I have to:
DeserializeObject - do some changes - SerializeObject
When my Json have miltiple types e.g.

```
{
  "type": "test",
  "currentStatus": "Active",
  "id": "987",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "test1",
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Segment Members",
      "memberCount": "0",
      "outputTerminals": [
        {
          "type": "test2",
          "id": "123",
          "connectedId": "123",
          "terminalType": "out"
        }
      ],
      "position": {
        "type": "Position",
        "x": "46",
        "y": "14"
      },
      "isFinished": "true",
      "isRecurring": "false",
      "segmentId": "123"
    },
    {
      "type": "test5",
      "id": "1390",
      "name": "Yay! Clickers",
      "memberCount": "2",
      "position": {
        "type": "Position",
        "x": "330",
        "y": "375"
      },
      "waitFor": "2592000"
    },
    {
      "type": "test3",
      "id": "1391",
      "name": "test",
      "memberCount": "73",
      "outputTerminals": [
        {
          "type": "test4",
          "id": "123",
          "connectedId": "123",
          "connectedType": "CampaignWaitAction",
          "terminalType": "yes"
        },
        {
          "type": "test4",
          "id": "123",
          "connectedId": "123",
          "connectedType": "CampaignWaitAction",
          "terminalType": "no"
        }
      ],
      "position": {
        "type": "Position",
        "x": "123",
        "y": "123"
      },
      "testId": "123"
    }
  ]
}
```

What data type i should use for this operation? dynamic, object, Jobject...? or maybe something else?

Comment: Try it out and be surprised, because you learned something today!

Answer (score 3):

I would just create an object and deseriablize it to that type. A lot easier than doing it dynamically. (assuming it will stay in that structure always)

**WHAT TO DO**

Copy your Json:

```
 `Edit` -> `Paste Special` -> `Paste JSON As CLASSES`
```

And there you go! You have the Type you want to deserialize to.

```
var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourNewObject>(jsonString);
```

*Note: if the pasting of the json class doesn't work, make sure your json is valid: [ClickHereToValidateJson](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)*

Answer (score 1):

You can create classes and serialize/deserialize json:

```
 public class OutputTerminal
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string connectedId { get; set; }
        public string terminalType { get; set; }
        public string connectedType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Position
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string x { get; set; }
        public string y { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string memberCount { get; set; }
        public IList<OutputTerminal> outputTerminals { get; set; }
        public Position position { get; set; }
        public string isFinished { get; set; }
        public string isRecurring { get; set; }
        public string segmentId { get; set; }
        public string waitFor { get; set; }
        public string testId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string currentStatus { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public IList<Item> items { get; set; }
    }
```

And then:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject);
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Also, you can use dynamic type without classes:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynamicObject);
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;          
dynamic collection = new
{
  MultipleType = //call function which returns json here
};
//serialize
var jsonSerializedFeed = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MultipleType);
//deserialize
var jsonSerializedFeed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MultipleType);
```

Hope it helps